# JavaEE Security,Access restricted pages: Logged out user is redirected correctly. Logged in user is not

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

My app is a Java EE 6 application, running on Glassfish 3.0.1.

I'm using Java EE Security, with a JDBC Realm. So i added restrictions to some of my web pages. 
I added the following login-config and security-constraint to my web.xml:

```
<!-- Redirect access of restricted pages to index.jsp -->
<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <realm-name>jdbc</realm-name>
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/index.jsp?login=login</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/index.jsp?login=error</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<!-- Restrict access for deanery related resources -->
<security-constraint>
  <display-name>Deanery Constraint</display-name>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Deanery Content</web-resource-name>
    <description />
    <url-pattern>/deanery/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <description />
    <role-name>DEANERY</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This works fine if a user is logged out. If he tries to access a page in /deanery/, he is redirected to the index.jsp (which redirects to jsf).

When a user logs in, getting the right role, he can successfully access the restricted resources. So everything is fine until here.

Now the problem: When a user with lesser rights (in my example a student) logs into the application, and tries to access a restricted page, he is NOT redirected to the error-page thats configured in my web.xml. Instead, he is shown an ugly Glassfish 403 page:

> HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied

Unfortunately, there seems no option to catch the exception in my [CustomExceptionHandler](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2009/09/03/dealing-gracefully-viewexpiredexception-jsf2). It even isn't shown in my server.log (although i switched to the finest level).

What can i do so the user is redirected to my error page, instead of displaying the 403 page? Why isn't the user redirected to the index.jsp, as he is when he is logged out???

**EDIT:**

Just tried to add an error-page with the corresponding code to my web.xml.

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>403</error-code>
  <location>/index.jsp?login=login</location>
</error-page>
```

No effect, still the Glassfish error-page instead of my own.

Answer (score 0):

I am just a newbie in javaEE but I think the problem is that the container redirects the users just after a 401 HTTP error, when he is not authorized. 403 Error means the it knows the username/pwd but it is not suitable for that resource.

So I would try to write a filter for this 403 error and redirect manually. Or you should hide the link to this page to students if this is possible.

Comment: I'm already hiding the links to restricted resources. But if someone types in the address into the browser, i want him to be displayed the correct message.

Comment: Why rate negative? Zoltan stated he was a newbie and he offered his solution, may be its not the recommended solution but he tried, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try 403 error redirect to different page than index.jsp that will display error message.

Comment: Thats no solution for me. When i do a generic redirect for all 403 errors, i cannot log some useful informations (which restricted resource was accessed? which user? etc.) and show some of these infos to the user.